# Can't see login screen

Tags: boot, login, monitor

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10. A few days ago the system started to set the monitor in sleep mode during boot up. Because of this I am unable to see the login screen.

However, I am able to hear the "Ubuntu sound" during boot up, and if I enter the password after the sound, the monitor is turned on agan after a few seconds and I can se the desktop. After that the system works as normal.

What's the problem and how can it be fixed?